# jquery Are You Sure? plugin: the confirm dialog is not showed if I click on an ajax link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I change a form and I click on ajax link, the confirm dialog is not showed and all changes are lost.

I tried this:

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
  $('form').trigger('checkform.areYouSure');
});
```

But It doesn't works. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, but it sounds like you may need to use a delegated event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If your link a href to a url try adding prevent default or set the href="#"

```
$("a").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $('form').trigger('checkform.areYouSure');
});
```